# php sendgrid - Using PHP with cURL example - not working

Tags: php, curl, sendgrid

I'm trying to use the same code that is posted on sendgrid's website of using the PHP's cURL function to query the sendgrid API.

The code I'm using is:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
$user = 'USERNAME';
$pass = 'PASSWORD';

$params = array(
    'api_user'  => $user,
    'api_key'   => $pass,
    'to'        => 'example3@sendgrid.com',
    'subject'   => 'testing from curl',
    'html'      => 'testing body',
    'text'      => 'testing body',
    'from'      => 'example@sendgrid.com',
  );


$request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

// Generate curl request
$session = curl_init($request);
// Tell curl to use HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
// Tell PHP not to use SSLv3 (instead opting for TLS)
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// obtain response
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);

// print everything out
print_r($response);

?>
```

But everytime I run it, this is the error I'm getting:

Notice: Use of undefined constant CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2 - assumed 'CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2'

I've literally scoured google but couldn't find any solution. Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've successfully got the above code working like this...
(I should also note it ended up in my spam due to the message content!)

```
$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
$user = 'USERNAME';
$pass = 'PASSWORD';

$params = array(
    'api_user'  => $user,
    'api_key'   => $pass,
    'to'        => 'example3@sendgrid.com',
    'subject'   => 'testing from curl',
    'html'      => 'testing body',
    'text'      => 'testing body',
    'from'      => 'example@sendgrid.com',
  );

$request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

// Generate curl request
$session = curl_init($request);
// Tell curl to use HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
// Tell PHP not to use SSLv3 (instead opting for TLS)
//curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);

//Turn off SSL
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);//New line
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);//New line

curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// obtain response
$response = curl_exec($session);

// print everything out
var_dump($response,curl_error($session),curl_getinfo($session));

curl_close($session);
```

Answer (score 1):

What PHP version are you running?

> **From http://php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php:**
>
> CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2 (integer)
>   Available since PHP 5.5.19 and 5.6.3

Your server is probably running a lower version than this, and the constant is undefined.

Comment: I've PHP version 5.6.3. Do I need to upgrade/downgrade this version?